# Unable to request authorization for local notifications on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, notifications, authorization, unusernotificationcenter

When requesting authorization for local notifications using:

```swift
do {
    _ = try await current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert])
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

I always get the error message:

> Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code=1 "Notifications are not allowed for this application" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Notifications are not allowed for this application}

If I go to

**System preferences** > **Notifications & Focus** > **My app name**

I can see that they are disabled, but I never disabled them myself and I can't find a way to reset the setting.

---

Using Swift, macOS 12 Monterey, and the updated `UserNotifications` API using async/await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to manually remove all traces of your app and try again from scratch, following all the steps listed here:

- Uninstall the app if it is installed (delete it from `Applications/`)
- Clean build on the Xcode project `⌘ ⇧ k`
- Remove any derived data `[path to Xcode]/Xcode/DerivedData`
- Remove any Xcode products `[path to Xcode]/Xcode/Products`
- Remove any archives `[path to Xcode]/Xcode/Archives`
- Remove your app's containers `~/Library/Containers/[my app name]`
- Empty the trash bin
- Do a search on finder to make sure there is no trace at all of your app anymore, search on your hard disk by the term: `[my app name].app`
- Make sure it doesn't appear anymore on: **System preferences** > **Notifications & Focus** > [My app name]
- Restart your computer

After all these steps requesting authorization should work:

```swift
do {
    _ = try await current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert])
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

#### It only works once

It will only work the first time, if you don't answer the notification or if you don't allow them you will need to repeat all the steps to try once more.