# Badge is not displaying OSX cocoa swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, badge, unusernotificationcenter

I am trying to display badge count in MacOS Ventura for my application, Here is my code

```
NSApplication.shared.dockTile.showsApplicationBadge = true
NSApplication.shared.dockTile.badgeLabel = "2"
NSApplication.shared.dockTile.display()
```

I also requested for notification allow

```
//create the notificationCenter
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self
    // set the type as sound or badge
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound,.alert,.badge]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            print("Notification Enable Successfully")
        }else{
            print(error.debugDescription) // prints "Notifications are not allowed for this application"
        }
    }
```

but it is always going into error part, I don't know what's issue there.
I also checked in Notification settings in System preference, It's showing only alert there. There is no badge setting there.

How to add badge setting in notification setting? Here is the screenshot

[image: Notification Setting]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Threre is an `error` parameter, why don't you print that?

Comment: @vadian error is Optional(Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code=1 "Notifications are not allowed for this application" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Notifications are not allowed for this application})

Comment: @vadian Updates questions with print statement in error part

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70039047/unable-to-request-authorization-for-local-notifications-on-macos

Comment: @vadian tried all steps mentioned in above answer but no luck

Comment: Is this a dock tile question or a user notification question?